# Polymer paper-dialog not centered

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

In my polymer app, when I open a paper-dialog using an iPhone, it's not centered, as opposed to opening it using Chrome or Safari using the a desktop Mac or PC.

I'm dynamically constructing the paper-dialog element and placing it in the DOM template using javascript, and then calling `open()`:

```
var d = document.createElement('paper-dialog');
d.innerHTML = "<h2>Dialog Title</h2>"
         "<p>some content</p>"+
         '<div class="buttons">'+
         "<paper-button >More Info...</paper-button>"+
         "<paper-button dialog-dismiss>Decline</paper-button>"+
         "<paper-button dialog-confirm autofocus>Accept</paper-button>"+
         "</div>";
var b = Polymer.dom(this.root).appendChild(d);
b.open();
```

I'm not using any special styles or media queries.
The reason I'm adding the dialog programatically is because I have tons of different dialog messages and different contents to show at different times, and each of them should call a callback at a different screen, depends on who added the dialog. in other words, I need to have my dialogs added like in [angular-material's $mdDialog](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.dialog), I know it's not that trivial for polymer, maybe not the intended use, but for my case that's what I need, unless there's a better way.

See screenshot of the problem below

iPhone:
[image]

Chrome:
[image]

Comment: Do you have any media queries set to max width 320px?

Comment: No, and the problem happens with all widths in iOS. in chrome desktop no matter how I resize the window, the dialog is centered correctly.

Comment: You should re-word your question then. This part : " when I open a paper-dialog using an iPhone, it's not centered," is implying that it is a possible problem with your view ports.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I don't see how it implies a viewport problem specifically. There are many differences between mobile safari and desktop safari/chrome, viewport is only one of them. It could be plethora of other things, could even be a bug in paper-dialog or webcomponents polyfill.

Comment: That is why I said a "possible" problem, of course there are others but you gave us no code! so its a guessing game. You should read "How to Ask a question on SO" and then try again.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Right, I've updated my question with some code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue was that I called `b.open();` right after `var b = Polymer.dom(this.root).appendChild(d);`.

Since I add the element dynamically, I should have put `b.open();` under a `this.async()` call, as mentioned in [polymer's documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html) for similar cases.

Also fixed the code in my [dialog-manager](https://github.com/aabluedragon/dialog-manager)

Comment: Nice job. It is very helpful when you answer your own questions and leave it for other to follow. Thanks. =]

Comment: Great! happy to help :}