# paper-dialog component is not centered on screen

Tags: javascript, meteor, polymer

I'm using Meteor `<template>`s and Polymer 0.5.

When I'm usign a `<paper-dialog>` in an element that fills the whole screen, the dialog appears centered on the screen because I think it's using the parent element's bounding box.

In my application, I use Meteor templates in a parent layout. In one of these child templates, I'm also using a Polymer dialog. Since this template doesn't fill the viewport and since the dialog is centered on it, the dialog is hideously displayed in the bottom-right of the page. If I enable the `layered` attribute on the dialog, it appears to be centered on the viewport. But I cannot use that attribute since it creates a shadow DOM and it breaks the way Meteor handles UI events (see [the only article I found about that](http://dev.elopernomi.com/making-meteor-polyer-paper-dialog-play-together-nicer/)).

The problem doesn't seems to be related to [this frequently-reported issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478360/polymer-paper-dialog-not-centered).

In the Polymer 1.0 documentation, I can see that the dialog object has `fit`, `refit` and `resetFit` methods to visually fit the dialog into a container of your choice. It seems to be the solution for my problem, but these methods seem to not exist in v0.5.

How can I set a `<paper-dialog>`'s container ?

Comment: If possible, switch to the latest Polymer...

Comment: Someone else in my team tried to upgrade Polymer one day but the application's UI exploded everywhere. I will try that to do that on my side, but the priority is to keep Polymer 0.5 to respect the deadlines :)

Comment: good luck with 0.5 !!! :)

Comment: do you know polyup? it is a tool google developed for migration purpose, I did not try it, but it might be worth in your case!

Comment: Very interesting projet, thank you! I will try that on monday.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following css should work.

```
html /deep/ .size-position {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the `/deep/` selector is not supported by Firefox and is deprecated. I'm searching for a long-term solution that is not using the shadow DOM for browser compatibility and Meteor-compatibility reasons.